# element wise matrix multiplication in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to speed up some `R` code with `Rcpp` that takes a vector of length L (psi) and a matrix of dimensions (L,L) and does some element-wise operations. Is there a more efficient way to be doing these element-wise operations with Rcpp?

r:

```
 UpdateLambda <- function(psi,phi){
                                      # updated full-day infection probabilites
    psi.times.phi <- apply(phi,1,function(x) x*psi)
    ## return Lambda_{i,j} = 1 - \prod_{j} (1 - \psi_{i,j,t} \phi_{i,j})
    apply(psi.times.phi,2,function(x) 1-prod(1-x))
  }
```

cpp:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace Rcpp;


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector UpdateLambdaC(NumericVector psi,
                NumericMatrix phi
                ){

  int n = psi.size();
  NumericMatrix psi_times_phi(n,n);
  NumericVector tmp(n,1.0);
  NumericVector lambda(n);

  for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
    psi_times_phi(i,_) = psi*phi(i,_);
   }

  for(int i=0; i<n;i++){
     // \pi_{j} (1- \lambda_{i,j,t})
    for(int j=0; j<n;j++){
      tmp[i] *= 1-psi_times_phi(i,j);
    }
     lambda[i] = 1-tmp[i];
  }

  return lambda;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you can avoid the use of `apply` in your R code, and use `colSums` with `log`ed variables to get the products.

Comment: The first `apply` is equivalent to `t(phi)*psi`, which should be faster

Comment: you think log and then exp'ing and summing will be that much faster than prods?

Comment: @scottyaz `colSums` is vectorized and very efficient. Unfortunately, there is no `colProds` in base R. Thats why @James suggested summing the logs. There is a function `colProds` in package `matrixStats`, which apparently uses this algorithm. The message is, that you probably don't need Rcpp if you optimize your R code.

Comment: @scottyaz I'll put the method down as an answer and you can see if it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You can replace you `apply` loops with vectorised alternatives.

The first one is equivalent to:

```
t(phi)*psi
```

And the second:

```
1-exp(colSums(log(1-psi.times.phi)))

#test data
phi <- matrix(runif(1e6),1e3)
psi <- runif(1e3)

#new function
UpdateLambda2 <- function(psi,phi) 1-exp(colSums(log(1-t(phi)*psi)))

#sanity check
identical(UpdateLambda(psi,phi),UpdateLambda2(psi,phi))
[1] TRUE

#timings
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(UpdateLambda(psi,phi),UpdateLambda2(psi,phi))
                     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
1  UpdateLambda(psi, phi)          100   16.05    1.041     15.06     0.93
2 UpdateLambda2(psi, phi)          100   15.42    1.000     14.19     1.19
```

Well, it appears that it does not make much of a difference, which is very surprising as `colSums` is typically much faster than `apply`. I'm not sure if the test data I've used is relevant as the output is all `1`'s due number of multiplications of number less than 1 in the second part. You may be better off working in a log scale anyway if you want to note the detail of such small numbers.